# How can I import pixi.js as a module in a vanilla JS project?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

File structure:

- index.html
- main.js
- pixi.js

My index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="main.js" type="module" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>
  </html>
```

main.js:

```
import * as PIXI from './pixi.js';
const app = new PIXI.Application({ 
    resizeTo:window,
    antialias: true,
    autoDensity: true,
    resolution: 2 });
  document.body.appendChild(app.view);
```

> Error: `Uncaught TypeError: PIXI.Application is not a constructor`

Other solutions tried:
This works properly when I import as a script tag e.g. `<script src="pixi.js" type="module"></script>` in `index.html` and then remove my import statement in `main.js`. A major downside of this approach is that I want to use JSDoc with linting, and under this method of importing it will not recognize `PIXI` as a valid type despite it being valid.
Another solution is to use a jsbundler and `import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'`, but this approach requires... a bundler. Can I just import it vanilla without extra tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use PixiJS in a static environment, first include a `<script />` linking to the CDN, or your own downloaded file if you'd like:

```html
<script src="https://pixijs.download/release/pixi.js"></script>
<!-- or -->
<script src="/pixi.js"></script>
```

Then, make your `main.js` and import it after:

```html
<script src="https://pixijs.download/release/pixi.js"></script>
<script src="/main.js"></script>
```

You can now use PixiJS in `main.js`. There's no need to use `type="module"`. If you want to import a library with a JavaScript `import` statement, you'll need to use a bundler.

Comment: I was afraid this was the only solution. The downside is that when I use `//@ts-check` for typechecking from my jsdocs it finds that `PIXI` is unknown because I don't explicitly import it. Too bad :/